# Tempdata session expires after browser close in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm creating login functionality for my site. I'm using **CI Sessions**. I've two sessions created in my **login model**.The first one is for the temp. user while the second is for the permanent user **(Remember me functionality)**. For the first one, I've the ***tempdata()*** & for the second one, i've the ***userdata()***. The **problem** i'm facing is that the session expires after the browser closes.

My **login model** code looks like this:

```
public function logger($email, $pass, $check)
        {
            $q = $this->DB->get_where('users', array('email' => $email, 'pass' => $pass));
            if($q->num_rows() == 1)
            {
                if(isset($check))
                {   
                    $this->session->set_tempdata('per_ue', $email, 86400*30);
                    $this->session->set_tempdata('per_up', $pass, 86400*30);
                    return redirect('uhome');
                } else {
                    $this->session->set_userdata('tmp_ue', $email);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('tmp_up', $pass);
                    return redirect('uhome');
                }
            } else {
                $login_error = '<p class="text-danger">Login credentials are incorrect</p>';
                $this->load->view('coders-community/login', compact('login_error'));
            }

        }
```

My **config** setting for session:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Could anyone tell me why tempdata **ttl (time-to-live)** not working & destrying **tempdata session** after browser closes?

Comment: temp session hold for only one refresh/page load of the site

Comment: So @Abdulla Nilam, is there anyway to set one session till browser close & another till a specific time?

Comment: You have not set your save path example `$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/';`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.Just set `$config['sess_expiration']` with certain amount of time.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;//sets session for 2 hours
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: I've tried this but It sets the expiration for both tempdata & userdata but i dont want this

Comment: Then you want to destroy session after closing browser.

Comment: I want to destroy userdata after browser close & tempdata after a specific time not after browser close

Comment: I dont think that you can manage expiration separately for userdata and tempdata. Because both data are working in identical session.

Comment: I've used cookies.That worked for me but I'm not satisfied with that because cookies are huge security risk

Comment: exactly possible using `cookies` but within same session i dont have much more experience.